Why does a ball bounce off the wall?
When we throw a ball onto a wall, the ball comes in contact with the wall. And the velocity of the ball comes from V m/s to 0m/s. According Newton’s first law, a force was acted on the ball by the wall (only external force can the motion of an object). And now, according to Newton’s third law, the ball should apply a force onto the wall. And after all this, why is the ball even bouncing? And what exactly is happening there?

Does this answer your question? Ball collision with a wall

Imagine that, instead of a rubber ball, you have thrown a massive rock, and imagine that instead of hitting the wall, the rock hits a perfect spring that is attached to the wall. What would you expect would happen in that case? A rubber ball behaves kind of like both a mass and a spring at the same time.
